# SQL Inner Join and further requirements

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I would like to return table entries from an inner join which do not have any matching entries in the second column.

Lets consider the following two tables:

Table one:

```
Name       Number
A          1
A          2
A          4
```

Table two:

```
Name       ID
A          3
```

The query should return Name=A ID=3. If ID would be 4, the query should not return anything. Is this even possible in SQL? Thanks for any hints!

Edit:
the joined table would look like this:

```
Name       Number    ID
A          1         3
A          2         3
A          4         3
```

So if I do this query I get no entries in the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE INNER JOIN TABLE_TWO ON TABLE_ONE.NAME=TABLE_TWO.NAME WHERE NUMBER=ID
```

Exactly in this situation I would like to get the Name returned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   Table1
         WHERE  Table1.Name = Table2.Name AND Table1.Number = Table2.ID
       )
```

Comment: this is logically the same as a full outer join -- which was my original point. it would be a good idea for you to investigate the performance differences between joins and not exist 'SELECT * FROM table2 t2 full outer join table1 t1 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.number = t2.id`

Comment: @rhealitycheck I consider the full outer join approach a hack (selecting the non existing matches of a FOJ is *just* a side effect); the `NOT EXISTS` construction exists for a thing, and this is the exact role it fullfills.

Comment: If `NOT EXISTS` performs worse than `FULL OUTER JOIN` then the RDBMS itself has a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, instead of using an INNER join, use a LEFT or a FULL OUTER join. This will allow null values from the other table to appear when you have a value in one of your tables.

The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1) and from the right table (table2).

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match. (There is also a RIGHT join, but it does the same thing as the left join, just returning all rows from the RIGHT table instead of the left).

Comment: I am not sure if I misunderstand your point. But in this case the result would be the same for an INNER JOIN and a LEFT JOIN, right? (I need to join the "Name" columns).

Comment: yes if you are joining just the name column it is the same, but if you have a name in your second table that doesn't have a reference in your first table. you could still do the join and get that id without having any references. because your name could have an ID associated with it but no number. that was the point.

Comment: okay thanks! But I am still stuck on how to only get Names which do not have any matching combination of Number/ID. (see my edited post).

Comment: i'm confused. so you want to get names where the number and id do not match so... for example if you had name = a and number = 3 in table 1 and name = a and id = 3 in table 2, do you want that returned?

Answer (score 0):

As @rhealitycheck has said, a full outer join would work. I found [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) blog post helpful in explaining joins. P.S. I can't leave comments (Otherwise I would have).